# Keyboard with letters and numbers on top (in Flutter)

Tags: flutter

Is there a possibility to have the keyboard appear with numbers above the letters. Something like this:

[image]

and this

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
/// Optimize for passwords that are visible to the user.
///
/// Requests a keyboard with ready access to both letters and numbers.
static const TextInputType visiblePassword = TextInputType._(7);
```

The above code portion is from the text_input.dart file. Therefore try the following. It might work, not sure though:

```
TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword
)
```

Comment: Works on android, but no numbers appear on ios

Comment: `visiblePassword` is a terrible name for this, since I didn't want it for a password at all. Exactly what I needed however.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that keyboard doesn't work on iOS is it doesn't exist as an available type. I used this package https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions to build a text/number keyboard on iOS and it works pretty well.

[image: keyboard image]